# Как на Python вывести все элементы после нужного и до следующего такого же?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, python-2.x, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вывести все элементы после нужного и до следующего такого же, пример:

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="1" class="а"></div>
<div id="2" class="а"></div>
<div id="3" class="а"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="4" class="а"></div>
<div id="5" class="а"></div>
<div id="6" class="а"></div>
```

Код:

```
b = soup.find_all("div", class_="header")
for i in b:
    s = i.find_next_siblings("div", class_="a")
    print(s)
```

На выходе получаю

```
[<div id="1" class="а"></div>
<div id="2" class="а"></div>
<div id="3" class="а"></div>,  
<div id="4" class="а"></div>
<div id="5" class="а"></div>
<div id="6" class="а"></div>]
[<div id="4" class="а"></div>
<div id="5" class="а"></div>
<div id="6" class="а">]
```

а надо:

```
[<div id="1" class="а"></div>
<div id="2" class="а"></div>
<div id="3" class="а"></div>]
[<div id="4" class="а"></div>
<div id="5" class="а"></div>
<div id="6" class="а">]
```

То есть мне нужно вывести все следующие элементы после `<div class="header"></div>` и до следующего `<div class="header"></div>`

Comment: За русские `а` вместо латинских `a` нужно по рукам бить :) Я 10 минут пытаюсь и так, и сяк написать парсер, а когда самое очевидное не сработало, уже проверил :) Неужто в том `html` реально русские `а` или ваша оплошность при ручном наборе данных?

Comment: моя, прошу прощения...

Comment: Бывает, ничего страшного :)

Comment: Вопрос. Допустим:
`<div class="header">Желтый</div>
<div id="1" class="a"></div>
<div id="2" class="a"></div>
<div id="3" class="a"></div>
<div class="header">Красный</div>
<div id="4" class="a"></div>
<div id="5" class="a"></div>
<div id="6" class="a"></div>` можно сделать, чтобы выводилось все только после того header, значение, которого удовлетворяет условию. Например, например, если div class="header" содержит "Желтый", то выводим, в остальных случаях нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Составил css-селектор, в котором указал, что нужны `div.a`, находящиеся по соседству с `div.header`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="header">Желтый</div>
<div id="1" class="a"></div>
<div id="2" class="a"></div>
<div id="3" class="a"></div>
<div class="header">Красный</div>
<div id="4" class="a"></div>
<div id="5" class="a"></div>
<div id="6" class="a"></div>
"""

root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

items = root.select("div.header ~ div.a")
print(items)
# [<div class="a" id="1"></div>, <div class="a" id="2"></div>, <div class="a" id="3"></div>, 
# <div class="a" id="4"></div>, <div class="a" id="5"></div>, <div class="a" id="6"></div>]
```

---

Доработка для поиска `div.a` у определенного `div.header`:

```
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

items = []
for header in root.find_all("div", class_='header'):
    # Нужен определенный цвет
    if header.get_text(strip=True) != 'Желтый':
        continue

    div = header
    while True:
        div = div.find_next_sibling('div')
        if not div or 'a' not in div.attrs['class']:
            break

        items.append(div)

print(items)
# [<div class="a" id="1"></div>, <div class="a" id="2"></div>, <div class="a" id="3"></div>]
```

Условие `if not div or 'a' not in div.attrs['class']: break` означает, что цикл будет прерван если `div` будет логическим `False` (например, если `None`) или если класса `a` не будет в атрибуте (например, если встретили `header`).

Если код немного доработать, то можно просто собирать группы тегов в словарь:

```
from collections import defaultdict
...

header_by_a = defaultdict(list)

for header in root.find_all("div", class_='header'):
    header_text = header.get_text(strip=True)
    
    div = header
    while True:
        div = div.find_next_sibling('div')
        if not div or 'a' not in div.attrs['class']:
            break

        header_by_a[header_text].append(div)

print(header_by_a['Желтый'])
# [<div class="a" id="1"></div>, <div class="a" id="2"></div>, <div class="a" id="3"></div>]

print(header_by_a['Красный'])
# [<div class="a" id="4"></div>, <div class="a" id="5"></div>, <div class="a" id="6"></div>]
```

Comment: Вопрос. Допустим: `<div class="header">Желтый</div> <div id="1" class="a"></div> <div id="2" class="a"></div> <div id="3" class="a"></div> <div class="header">Красный</div> <div id="4" class="a"></div> <div id="5" class="a"></div> <div id="6" class="a"></div>` можно сделать, чтобы выводилось все только после того header, значение, которого удовлетворяет условию. Например, например, если div class="header" содержит "Желтый", то выводим, в остальных случаях нет.

Comment: этим способом вы вывели все элементы ниже div.header одним списком, а нужно чтобы для каждого div.header выводились все div.a, но до следующего div.header. То есть как изначально я писал, но на выходе вот такое нужно ``[<div id="1" class="а"></div>
<div id="2" class="а"></div>
<div id="3" class="а"></div>]
[<div id="4" class="а"></div>
<div id="5" class="а"></div>
<div id="6" class="а">]``

Comment: @ChikChirik, обновил ответ

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, как первый ваш вариант изменить, чтобы на выходе было не `# [<div class="a" id="1"></div>, <div class="a" id="2"></div>, <div class="a" id="3"></div>, 
# <div class="a" id="4"></div>, <div class="a" id="5"></div>, <div class="a" id="6"></div>]`, а   ---------`# [[<div class="a" id="1"></div>, <div class="a" id="2"></div>, <div class="a" id="3"></div>],  
# [<div class="a" id="4"></div>, <div class="a" id="5"></div>, <div class="a" id="6"></div>]]`

Comment: @ChikChirik, давайте я вам отвечу в https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056741 заодно и закроем тот вопрос. Этот вопрос ведь к тому вопросу соотносится, да? По хорошему, нужно один вопрос -- один ответ, а изменение вопроса, под разные хотелки не круто ) А так, не понимаю вашей проблемы... Заводите вне цикла список, внутри цикла создаете список для добавления div.a внутри while и после цикла while добавляете список для div.a в список, что был создан вне первого цикла for. Простенький алгоритм

Comment: получилось, еще раз огромное спасибо)

Comment: @ChikChirik, вы молодец, что сами справились :)

Comment: да уж, если бы сам)) без вас точно не справился бы) ну или потратил еще кучу времени..