# Как проверить содержит ли нужный атрибут нужный div на python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как проверить содержит ли `div` нужный `class`.

Код:

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="1" class="a"></div>
<div id="2" class="a"></div>
<div id="3" class="a"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="4" class="a"></div>
<div id="5" class="a"></div>
<div id="6" class="a"></div>
```

```py
b = soup.find_all("div", class_="header")
for i in b:
    s = i.find_next_siblings("div")
    for div in s:
        while True:
            # Нужно проверить если div содержит class="a", то делаем то-то 
            #если содержит class="header", то break. То есть нужно вывести 
            #все классы, содержащие class="a" ниже сlass="header", но до 
            #следующего сlass="header"
            # Не пойму какой нужен синтаксис, пробовал несколько вариантов
            #if "event__match" in div.attrs["class"]:
            #ошибка  if "event__header" in div.attribute["class"]:
            #TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Количество div header и div class a пропорционально и равное 3?

Comment: Я в том ответе вам показывал как это делать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1056355/201445 Это проверка `'a' not in div.attrs['class']` на то, что класса `a` нет, соответственно, это проверка, что класс `a` есть `'a' in div.attrs['class']`. Аналогично делайте для других классов

Comment: `Количество div header и div class a пропорционально и равное 3? ` - нет может быть в любом количестве.

Comment: `Я в том ответе вам показывал как это делать: ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1056355/201445 Это проверка 'a' not in div.attrs['class'] на то, что класса a нет, соответственно, это проверка, что класс a есть 'a' in div.attrs['class']. Аналогично делайте для других классов` - выдает ошибку if "event__header" in div.attribute["class"]: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @ChikChirik, вы не видите разницу между `div.attrs` и `div.attribute`? :) Нет у объектов `div.attribute`, поэтому его значение `None`, а у `None` вызывать квадратные скобки это к ошибке `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: это я скопировал ошибку, когда уже пробовал вариант с attribute, но изначально я и `if "event__match" in div.attrs["class"]:` пробовал, как и написал

Comment: А если ли в атрибуте class значения `event__match`? Лучше к проблеме с кодом предоставляйте и пример html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите,

- Код `for i in soup.find_all("div", class_="header")` вернет все `div.header`. Вы их в цикле получаете
- Код `for div in i.find_next_siblings("div")` вернет всех соседей, от текущего `i` (т.е. от текущего `div.header`). А это не только `div.a`, но последующие за ними `div.header` и его `div.a`
- Поэтому, нам и нужно остановится на первом попавшемся внутри `div.header`
- А сам цикл `while` не нужен

Пример:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="1" class="a"></div>
<div id="2" class="a"></div>
<div id="3" class="a"></div>
<div class="header"></div>
<div id="4" class="a"></div>
<div id="5" class="a"></div>
<div id="6" class="a"></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all("div", class_="header"):
    print('HEADER')

    for div in i.find_next_siblings("div"):
        class_ = div.attrs['class']

        if 'a' in class_:
            print(f'    {div}')
        elif 'header' in class_:
            break
```

Вывод:

```
HEADER
    <div class="a" id="1"></div>
    <div class="a" id="2"></div>
    <div class="a" id="3"></div>
HEADER
    <div class="a" id="4"></div>
    <div class="a" id="5"></div>
    <div class="a" id="6"></div>
```

Comment: спасибо, за уделенное время)